# Caused by: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/lp/LP.2015.4.28.10.29.40.zip is not a file or doesn't exist

Tags: java, file

This is how my code looks

```
protected Response uploadFile(final File file) throws HttpUploadException {
    System.out.println("Uploader uploading " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("Uploader file exists " + file.exists());
    final String endPoint = endPoint.getAppURL() + "/" + uri;
    final Response response;
    try {
      response =
          remoteResource.uploadFileAndGetResponse(endPoint, file.getAbsoluteFile(), "application/octet-stream",
                                                         Collections.<String, String>emptyMap());

    } catch (final Exception e) {
      throw new HttpUploadException("Failed to upload data to " + endPoint, e);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I see

```
Uploader uploading /tmp/lp/LP.2015.4.28.10.29.40.zip
Uploader file exists true
```

and then I see exception as

```
com.pro.logs.client.HttpUploadException: Failed to upload data to https://mystat.pro.net:443/importer
    at com.shn.logs.common.Uploader.uploadFile(Uploader.java:54)
    at com.pro.logs.controller.report.LPDiagnosticReportUploader.upload(LPDiagnosticReportUploader.java:12)
    at com.pro.logs.controller.report.ReportSender$ReportSenderRunnable.executeTasks(ReportSender.java:109)
    at com.pro.logs.controller.report.ReportSender$ReportSenderRunnable.run(ReportSender.java:92)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/lp/LP.2015.4.28.10.29.40.zip is not a file or doesn't exist
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.construct(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:891)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.buildRequest(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:657)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener$Builder.build(NettyConnectListener.java:145)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.doConnect(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1071)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:940)
    at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:499)
    at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient$BoundRequestBuilder.execute(AsyncHttpClient.java:229)
    at com.shn.util.RemoteResourceManager.uploadFileAndGetResponse(RemoteResourceManager.java:137)
    at com.pro.logs.common.Uploader.uploadFile(Uploader.java:50)
    ... 6 more
```

When the file already exists, what's the issue?

Comment: `isFile()` only returns true if the file is `"not a directory and, in addition, satisfies other system-dependent criteria"`.  You might try checking if you're pointing at a soft link or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that is becauze `ZIP` file is not a `File`

```
System.out.println("Uploader file isFile? " + file.isFile());
```

I see

```
Uploader file isFile? false
```

I have a different problem now